# integer to string issue

Tags: java

In my Java program I receive a string from my Arduino by the serial port.
The string is stored in variable (string) : result.

An example of what the data could be: 'w: 125' (always 1 character, a colon, and a space, with a analog value from my Arduino)

In my code I do:

```
int spacePos = result.indexOf(" "); // search where the space is
number= result.substring(spacePos+1); // take everything what comes behind the space
System.out.println(number); // print the value, example : 125
int number2 = Integer.parseInt(number);// this should convert the String 125 to a integer with value 125
System.out.println(number2);// should print a integer with value 125
```

The part with substring works; I think. When I print the number I can see the 125 in the output screen of NetBeans, but I can select a few spaces??? behind my number.
But when I print number2, I don't see anything.

Any assistance you may provide is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: does it throw any exception ??

Comment: What is the length of `number` - could it be there are some unexpected characters after the `"125"` that are throwing the parser off? Can you trim the string before parsing?

Comment: are you sure that `result` contains `w: 125`?

Answer (score 0):

You `number= result.substring(spacePos+1);` has trailing whitespace behind the number. You need to remove the whitespace, that is leading to the conversion error by parsing the Integer. for Example use

```
int spacePos = result.indexOf(" ");
String number = result.substring(spacePos+1);
number = number.trim();//removes trailing whitespace
int number2 = Integer.parseInt(number);
System.out.println(number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the spaces before the number, then you have more than one space between the `:` and the number. Do either this:

```
int spacePos = result.lastIndexOf(" ");
```

Or do this:

```
int number2 = Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that there are extra spaces in the string that is passed to `parseInt` which will cause a `NumberFormatException` and line `System.out.println(number2)` will not be reached. If you have some code that looks like

```
try {
  /* ... */
} catch (Exception e) {
  /* do nothing */
}
```

it is keeping you from seeing the runtime error.